# Eclipse error while running a code with Stringbuilder

Tags: java, eclipse

Please help me out in out to get rid of this error. Whereas i tried the same code in Command line it was working perfectly without any exceptions.

```
public class String {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuilder nb = new StringBuilder("");

        nb.append("<string1>");
        nb.append("<string2>");

        System.out.println(nb.toString());
    }
}
```

Error: Main method not found in class String, please define the main method as:

> public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class
>   must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: You know that `String` is already a class in Java right :)

Comment: You should not have a class named String in Java; you already have java.lang.String.  Couldn't you call this InvalidXmlDemo instead?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Don't name your class `String` as `String` is also a "build-in" type of Java (java.lang.String).